# modsecurity for iis not logging request body

Tags: mod-security2

We have an ASP.Net/angular/web api on IIS 7.5 that is being called with bad encoding and we're trying to get the request body logged so we can show the problem to the caller.

We googled around and found ModSecurity, so we installed it and are giving it a try - but only for the Audit Logging portion.  Unfortunately, neither C nor I seem to be logging anything, no matter what we do.  I've seen some other Oflow posts that I infer to mean ModSecurity only logs those types for certain incoming requests (.html logs C but nothing else does kind of thing).  WebApi and angular might be confusing it, but I'm not sure.  Nothing I've tried seems to work.

Here's our configuration:

```
# -- Audit log configuration -------------------------------------------------

# Log the transactions that are marked by a rule, as well as those that
# trigger a server error (determined by a 5xx or 4xx, excluding 404,  
# level response status codes).
#
SecAuditEngine On
SecRequestBodyAccess On

# Log everything we know about a transaction.
SecAuditLogParts ABCIJDEFHZ

# Use a single file for logging. This is much easier to look at, but
# assumes that you will use the audit log only ocassionally.
#
SecAuditLogType Serial
SecAuditLog E:\ModLogs\modsec_audit4.log
```

Is there something else I've got to do to get ModSecurity to do the C/I logging?

ModSecurity 2.9.1 (downloaded today), IIS 7.5, Web Api, Angular, ASP.Net

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a known bug with ModSecurity and IIS: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/issues/538

Near the bottom of that bug there are comments that this can be resolved by setting this in your config:

```
SecStreamInBodyInspection On
```

There are also [some posts](https://forums.iis.net/t/1196659.aspx?Getting%20ModSecurity%20IIS%202%207%202%20to%20work%20on%20IIS%207%205%208%200) suggesting disabling DynamicCompression in IIS is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for you answer and the links.  I tried having SecStreamInBodyInspection On (and turning SecRequestBodyAccess Off) to no avail.  Still no body logging with C or I.  On my dev site, I don't have DynamicCompression installed (I double-checked after your link).  Finally gave up and wrote a little http module to approximate it.